# Has anyone noticed that the height of the sun on the horizon is nearly 1 degree?

Tags: geometry

I have timed the difference between the first showing of the sun on the horizon to when the sun's bottom first clears the horizon.  I am thinking that this is the reason we have 360 degrees in a circle.  The time is nearly 1/360 of a day.

Comment: There's a lot of history on why the Babylonians opted for $360$ degrees in a circle: many divisors, close to the number of days in a year. Probably not what you imagine here.

Comment: IIRC the sun's diameter is about 1.4 million kilometers. The distance is 150 million km, so the angle is a bit less then one hundredth of a radian ($1/100 rad \approx 0.57^\circ$). At sunrise / sunset [atmospheric refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction) distorts your timing data significantly, which is why you got the correct value roughly doubled).

Answer (score 1):

The visual diameter of sun is $31.6 - 32.7$ minutes (about $0.5$ degree).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun